# Matchmaker auto-match does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I have followed the tutorial of `Ray Wenderlich` [How to make a multiplayer game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12), following all the steps. I am using `my iphone` and the `simulator` to test it:

- The players authenticate on both devices (`iOS 7` both of them)
- I use two different `SANDBOX` `game center` ids for both of `devices`
- The `game center view controller` fires up correctly
- I use choose "`Play Now`" on both devices, but it hangs forever in searching a match.
- If I choose `Cancel`, the callback of the delegate:

  -(void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController
  {
           NSLog(@"Canceled");
  }

is being called correctly.

So I suppose is a `Game Center settings` error, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using same network for both devices ? GC has some problems which connecting from share public IP :(

Comment: Yes, it worked, great! Thank you! I connected both of them to my Wi-Fi access point and they connected!  But I wonder how it is gonna work later. Should all the players be connected at the same subnet?

Comment: I think it's only Sandbox problem. We didn't have those problems on live environment. What's more you might even have some problems with invitations while working on same network :(

Comment: Also keep in mind - invitation are not gonna work from simulator - you need 2 devices

Comment: Oh thank you for the advices, they will save me a lot of time. I wonder how can I get two testing devices. By the way, post an answer to this question and I will approve it. Might help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameCenter has problem when connecting device through shared public IP.
It goes crazy in terms of matchmaking giving false connection results and returning number of players required to start the game or not connecting at all.

Also keep in mind that from Simulator you cannot test invitations.